# Is Blockchain.info Open Source?

Tags: open-source, blockchain.info, license

I know that there is a github public repo, but I'm not seeing a license file. The Android client is GPL3. Anyone know about licensing for the main site's code?

Comment: Propose update for 2017 status.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All parts directly involved with the wallet service are open source. On the [github project page](https://github.com/blockchain) the repositories My-Wallet, My-Wallet-Integrity-Checker and MyWallet-RPC-Communicator is BSD licensed.

The repositories My-Wallet-iPhone, My-Wallet-Android are GPLv3.

However the database backend and some other parts of the site are not open source. This will change at some point in time, but there are some things I want to finish first.

Comment: Ben: I'm very interested in an open source database, listener, etc for bitcoin. Please keep me updated!

Comment: I'm interested in this too :) Please keep us updated here as well! Thanks!

Comment: There is an interesting project related too: https://github.com/lirazsiri/blockexplorer

Comment: I'm interesting in submitting minor changes to the HTML of blockchain.info (primarily to add an `id` attribute to the headers on this page: https://blockchain.info/charts).  Is the blockchain.info website open source, and if so, where can I find it?

Comment: Now 2017, what is the status. Is the answer the same?